# findandupdate return null with promise all - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a nodejs API separated by controllers and routes. I am trying to findandupdate in multiple collections and then put them in multiple promises to return a single response but i get just a `null` what am i doing wrong below ?

**controller.js**

```
var x = (req, res, next, userID, product) => {

    let query = {
        uid: userID
    }

    let update = {
        $push: {
            product: product,
        }
    }

    let options = {
        safe: true,
        new: true,
        upsert: true
    }

    Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).exec()
    .then(result => {
        return true
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    })
};

module.exports = x;
```

**Route.js**

```
const controller = require('./user-product')
router.post('/api', function (req, res, next) {
    var p1 = controller(req, res, next, userID, product)        
    var allDone = Promise.all([p1])
    allDone
        .then(function (e) {
            res.send(e) //this is null
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning promise from the controller function. You are just returning the `result` and the `error`

So, Instead you should return the promise inside the controller function

**Route.js**

```
const controller = require('./user-product')
router.post('/api', function (req, res, next) {
  var p1 = controller(req, res, next, userID, product)        
  var allDone = Promise.all([p1])
  allDone.then(function (e) {
    res.send(e)
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
})
```

**controller.js**

```
var x = (req, res, next, userID, product) => {
  let query = { uid: userID }
  let update = { $push: { product: product }}
  let options = {
      safe: true,
      new: true,
      upsert: true
  }
  return Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).exec()
}

module.exports = x;
```

And probably easier with the **async await** syntax

**Route.js**

```
const controller = require('./user-product')
router.post('/api', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const p1 = await controller(req, res, next, userID, product)
    console.log(p1)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

**controller.js**

```
var x = async(req, res, next, userID, product) => {
  let query = { uid: userID }

  let update = { $push: { product: product }}

  let options = {
      safe: true,
      new: true,
      upsert: true
  }
  return Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options).exec()
}

module.exports = x;
```